# Changing label name for algorithm

Tags: captions, naming, algorithm2e

I have this algorithm:

```
\begin{algorithm}
\captionsetup[algorithm]{name=MegaAlgorithm}

\DontPrintSemicolon
\KwData{$G=(X,U)$ such that $G^{tc}$ is an order.}
\KwResult{$G’=(X,V)$ with $V\subseteq U$ such that $G’^{tc}$ is an
interval order.}

\caption{\textsc{Fast}SLAM\label{IR}}
\end{algorithm}
```

Using these packages:

```
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[ruled,vlined]{algorithm2e}
```

But the label name of my algorihm is still 'Algorithm 1: FastSLAM' instead of 'MegaAlgorithm 1: FastSLAM'. How to do that?

Comment: I think you need to recompile yoor source several times to overwrite `*.aux` and other files.

Comment: I'm using `rm *.ps *.log *.aux *.dvi` in my Makefile. So `*.aux` files should be overwriten.

Comment: `\captionsetup[algorithm]{name=MegaAlgorithm}` after `\begin{algorithm}` is too late since the options declared with `\captionsetup[algorithm]{...}` will be used at `\begin{algorithm}`. So try `\captionsetup[algorithm]{name=MegaAlgorithm}` within your preamble instead, or as an alternative try `\captionsetup{name=MegaAlgorithm}` after `\begin{algorithm}`. But since the `caption` package is not adapted to the `algorithm2e` package there is a big chance that this will actually not work.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

For the sake of consistency, define a new environment that uses the `MegaAlgorithm` caption style. Not sure whether you will intermix regular `Algorithm`s and `MegaAlgorithm`s, which this solution is geared towards:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ruled,vlined]{algorithm2e}

\newenvironment{megaalgorithm}[1][htb]
  {\renewcommand{\algorithmcfname}{MegaAlgorithm}% Update algorithm name
   \begin{algorithm}[#1]%
  }{\end{algorithm}}

\begin{document}
\begin{megaalgorithm}
  \DontPrintSemicolon
  \KwData{$G=(X,U)$ such that $G^{tc}$ is an order.}
  \KwResult{$G’=(X,V)$ with $V\subseteq U$ such that $G’^{tc}$ is an interval order.}
  \caption{\textsc{Fast}SLAM}
\end{megaalgorithm}
\begin{algorithm}
  \DontPrintSemicolon
  \KwData{$G=(X,U)$ such that $G^{tc}$ is an order.}
  \KwResult{$G’=(X,V)$ with $V\subseteq U$ such that $G’^{tc}$ is an interval order.}
  \caption{\textsc{Fast}SLAM}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

The new `megaalgorithm` environment redefines `\algorithmcfname` - the macro used to print the caption type - just before calling the regular `algorithm` environment. Since the redefinition is within the scope of `megaalgorithm`, it is localized and reverts back to the default afterwards. This allows you to intermix the different kinds of algorithm types.

---

If you wish to have a separate counter for **MegaAlgorithm** and **Algorithm**, you can use the following definition of `megaalgorithm` in your preamble:

```
\makeatletter
\newcounter{megaalgorithm}
\newenvironment{megaalgorithm}[1][htb]
  {\renewcommand{\algorithmcfname}{MegaAlgorithm}% Update algorithm name
   \let\c@algocf\c@megaalgorithm% Update algorithm counter
   \begin{algorithm}[#1]%
  }{\end{algorithm}}
\makeatother
```

Answer (score 11):

Its simpler:

With `algorithm2e` package, solution will be as follows: [ My working copy of algorithm2e.sty is [here](http://bay.uchicago.edu/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/algorithm2e/tex/algorithm2e.sty) ]

```
\usepackage[ruled,vlined]{algorithm2e}
.
.

\begin{algorithm}
 \SetAlgorithmName{MegaAlgorithm}{} %last arg is the title of listing table
   ...
 \caption{How to write algorithm}
\end{algorithm}
```

---

Aside, since there is a considerable community using `algorithmicx` package (especially IEEE authors), here is the solution of the same problem with `algorithmicx` package:

```
\usepackage{algorithmicx}
\usepackage[Algorithm,ruled]{algorithm}
.
.

\begin{algorithm}
 \floatname{algorithm}{MegaAlgorithm}
  \begin{algorithmic}
    ...
  \end{algorithmic}
 \caption{How to write algorithm}
\end{algorithm}
```

Comment: Note that `\SetAlgorithmName` takes **3** arguments, not 2! (probably recent change? The example in the documentation is also wrong)