# Change name of algorithm

Tags: algorithms, naming

I've been trying to use this answer [Changing label name for algorithm](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/104430/changing-label-name-for-algorithm) to no avail. I use the packages:

```
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
```

And this code for defining new environment:

```
\newenvironment{megaalgorithm}[1][htb]{
    \renewcommand{\algorithmcfname}{MegaAlgorithm}% Update algorithm name
   \begin{algorithm}[#1]%
  }{\end{algorithm}}
```

But then it tells me that there is an error:

> Latex Error: \algorithmcfname undefined

I can't use `algorithm2e` as in previous example as it breaks my current code.

Comment: Untested, due to the lack of an MWE: `\makeatletter\renewcommand{\ALG@name}{MEGAAlgorithm}\makeatother`

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The right one when using the `algorithm` package is `\ALG@name` and not `\algorithmcfname`.

So you have to define your new environment as

```
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{megaalgorithm}[1][htb]{%
    \renewcommand{\ALG@name}{MegaAlgorithm}% Update algorithm name
   \begin{algorithm}[#1]%
  }{\end{algorithm}}
\makeatother
```

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{megaalgorithm}[1][htb]{%
    \renewcommand{\ALG@name}{MegaAlgorithm}% Update algorithm name
   \begin{algorithm}[#1]%
  }{\end{algorithm}}
\makeatother

\begin{document} 

\begin{megaalgorithm}
\begin{algorithmic}
\State Hello
\end{algorithmic}
\caption{A mega algorithm}
\end{megaalgorithm}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

In `algorithm.sty` (part of the `algorithms` bundle) you can find:

```
\newcommand{\ALG@name}{Algorithm}
```

and

```
\floatname{algorithm}{\ALG@name}
```

So, another option is to define your new environment as

```
\newenvironment{megaalgorithm}[1][htb]{%
    \floatname{algorithm}{MegaAlgorithm}% Update algorithm name
   \begin{algorithm}[#1]%
  }{\end{algorithm}}
```

The first method is taken directly from the style file, while the latter can be found in subsection 4.4, "Customization", of the [`algorithms`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/algorithms) [documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/algorithms/algorithms.pdf)

Comment: Thank you! For the future, where should I look for things like `\ALG@name`, I haven't been able to find anything like this in the algorithmicx documentation.

Comment: @paewel You're welcome. I've added some explanations in the edit.

Comment: How can I use separate numbering for this new environment. My document has both the basic algorithm environment as well as the newly defined one.

Comment: My first instinct would be to use `\floatname{algorithm}{MegaAlgorithm}`, since that's what the package manual says to use. Why might you want to use `\renewcommand{\ALG@name}{MegaAlgorithm}` (surrounded by `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`)?