# Changing name of the label Algorithm

Tags: algorithms, naming

When using `algorithmx` you get "Algorithm 1 algorithm name". How can you change the label "Algorithm"? I do not mean individually for each algorithm, but instead changing it globally the whole latex project. The reason for this is because I rather want it to say "algoritme", which is algorithm in Norwegian.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[norsk]{babel} 
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{apacite}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\State a
\label{a}
\caption{name}
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You need to be clear on what packages you're using. [`algorithmicx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx) provides `\ALG@name`.

Comment: See [Change name of algorithm](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/230497/5764).

Comment: Updated it now. Your link isn't for changing the label Algorithm globally.

Comment: Worked, add your solution and ill accept it :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To some extent this is discussed in the post [Change name of algorithm](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/230497/5764). This answer addresses the same content, but also some other issues:

- To change the algorithm naming, add

  ```
    \makeatletter
    \renewcommand{\ALG@name}{Algoritme}
    \makeatother
  ```

in your preamble *after* `\usepackage{algorithm}`.

- The `algorithmic` environment should not have a `\caption`; that should be used in the `algorithm` (float) environment;
- You should always [place the `\label` *after* `\caption`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/32325/5764).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\ALG@name}{Algoritme} %Change the name Algorithm to Algoritme
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
  \caption{name}\label{a}
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \State a
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```