# Writing code in LaTeX

Tags: listings, algorithms

Supeeer new to Latex so I'm sorry if my question is stupid.

I have a programming assignment using pseudo-code for one of my courses. Our professor suggested we do the assignment using LaTeX. Can anyone guide my how to format the code using LaTeX?

I should make it look like this:

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Take a look [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/163768/134574) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25425/134574).

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Print programs with its proper syntax](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25425/5764)

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik that's exactly what I was looking for thank you! One more question though, do you know how to change "Algorithm 1" to something else?

Comment: @VakiPitsi See if [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/230656/134574) works for you

Comment: Thank you everyone!

Comment: "Supeeer new to Latex" At this stage consider use LyX and learn from the code generated when this program make  common LaTeX structures (including algorithm floats).

Comment: @Fran Thanks for the advice I'll check it out