# Change name in pseudocode

Tags: pseudocode

I am writing my code in **pseudocode** package and I would need to change the name "**Algorithm**" to "**Algoritmus**".

Is there any possibility how to do this in this package? I have found it just for package algorithm, but I have everything written and I don't want to change my whole work to different environment.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Possible duplicates: [Change name of algorithm](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/230497/5764); [How to change the name of document elements like "Figure", "Contents", "Bibliography", "Appendix", etc.?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/82993/5764)

Comment: @Werner It doesn't seem to be a duplicate as the issues are particular to this package

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: True. Read "possible duplicates" as "related". :-|

Comment: @AboAmmar that says how to redefine `\ALG@name` which won't help here,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

packages should use `\xxxname` commands for fixed strings so that they can be easily changed as you request but unfortunately this uses the fixed text in the middle of a large command setup.

However you can patch the definition as follows

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pseudocode}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\expandafter\patchcmd\csname\string\pseudocode\endcsname{Algorithm}{Algoritmus}{\typeout{good}}{\typeout{bad}}
\expandafter\patchcmd\csname\string\pseudocode\endcsname{Algorithm}{Algoritmus}{\typeout{good}}{\typeout{bad}}
\begin{document}

\begin{pseudocode}{a}{b}

\end{pseudocode}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\xpatchcmd{\pseudocode}{Algorithm}{Algoritmus}{}{}` is easier, with `\xpatch`. Nice package, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

David's patch is good, but it can be largely improved, for instance making the name language aware and adding easy support for changing the formatting of the header.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,czech]{babel}

\usepackage{pseudocode}
\usepackage{xpatch}

% fix the bad code in pseudocode.sty
\xpatchcmd\pseudocode{\bfseries Algorithm }{\algorithmheadformat\algorithmname\ }{}{}
\xpatchcmd\pseudocode{\bfseries Algorithm }{\algorithmheadformat\algorithmname\ }{}{}
\providecommand{\algorithmname}{Algorithm}
\providecommand{\algorithmheadformat}{\bfseries}
% end of fix

\addto\captionsczech{\renewcommand{\algorithmname}{Algoritmus}}
\addto\captionsenglish{\renewcommand{\algorithmname}{Algorithm}}
\renewcommand{\algorithmheadformat}{\scshape}

\begin{document}

\begin{pseudocode}{CelsiusToFahrenheit}{c}
  f \GETS {9c/5} + 32\\
  \RETURN{f}
\end{pseudocode}

\selectlanguage{english}

\begin{pseudocode}{CelsiusToFahrenheit}{c}
  f \GETS {9c/5} + 32\\
  \RETURN{f}
\end{pseudocode}

\end{document}
```

I added `\renewcommand{\algorithmheadformat}{\scshape}` just by way of example.

[image]