# New algorithm environment with a separate counter

Tags: environments, counters, algorithmic, algpseudocode

I am trying to define a new environment called protocol, which is the same as the algorithm environment, except for the title and counter. I used [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/230497/change-name-of-algorithm) as my guideline. However, it does not reset the counter. Here is my code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{protocol}[1][htb]{%
    \renewcommand{\ALG@name}{Protocol}% Update algorithm name
    \begin{algorithm}[#1]%
    }{\end{algorithm}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \begin{algorithm}
        \caption{Algo Test}
        \label{algo:test}
        \begin{algorithmic}
            \State $x \gets y + 1$
        \end{algorithmic}
    \end{algorithm}

    \begin{protocol}
    \caption{Prot Test}
    \label{prot:test}
        \begin{algorithmic}
            \State $x \gets y + 1$
        \end{algorithmic}
    \end{protocol}
\end{document}
```

Here is my output:
[image: Test Output]

Protocol and Algorithm environments are both using the same counter. How can I get a separate counter for each?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest solution is to pretend that the counter is `algorithm` inside of the `protocol` environment but is the `protocol`in fact.

This can be done without any harm with `\let\c@algorithm\c@protocol` within the `protocol` environment, since `\c@protocol` is the internal name of the `protocol` count register.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\newcounter{protocol}
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{protocol}[1][htb]{%
  \let\c@algorithm\c@protocol
  \renewcommand{\ALG@name}{Protocol}% Update algorithm name
  \begin{algorithm}[#1]%
  }{\end{algorithm}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
See \ref{prot:yetanother}

    \begin{algorithm}
        \caption{Algo Test}
        \label{algo:test}
        \begin{algorithmic}
            \State $x \gets y + 1$
        \end{algorithmic}
    \end{algorithm}

    \begin{protocol}
    \caption{Prot Test}
    \label{prot:test}
        \begin{algorithmic}
            \State $x \gets y + 1$
        \end{algorithmic}
    \end{protocol}


    \begin{algorithm}
        \caption{Algo Test}
        \label{algo:testother}
        \begin{algorithmic}
            \State $x \gets y + 1$
        \end{algorithmic}
    \end{algorithm}

    \begin{protocol}
    \caption{Prot Test}
    \label{prot:testother}
        \begin{algorithmic}
            \State $x \gets y + 1$
        \end{algorithmic}
    \end{protocol}

    \begin{protocol}
    \caption{Prot Test}
    \label{prot:yetanother}
        \begin{algorithmic}
            \State $x \gets y + 1$
        \end{algorithmic}
    \end{protocol}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I agree. this is a better approach.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you want to use independent counters for `algorithms` and `protocols`. As far as I can see the [algorithm](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/algorithm) package does not allow this and only works with the `algorithm` counter. So, what you need to do is "trick" the `algorithmic` environment to use separate counters. Do do this you should set up two *new* counters: one to keep track of the number of protocols and one to keep track of the algorithms. In the MWE below I have defined them as:

```
\newcounter{protocol}%        counter for protocols
\newcounter{algorithm saved}% the real counter for algorithms
```

The `algorithmic` environment will happily use the `algorithm` counter. When you switch to your `protocol` environment you need to switch to using the `protocol` counter -- and at the same time save the current value of the `algorithm` counter. If you "swap" back to using the `algorithm` counter at the end of the `protocol` environment then everything will remain in sync.

The following MWE does what you want:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}

\newcounter{protocol}%        counter for protocols
\newcounter{algorithm saved}% the real counter for algorithms

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{protocol}[1][htb]{%
    \renewcommand{\ALG@name}{Protocol}% Update algorithm name
    \setcounter{algorithm saved}{\value{algorithm}} % switch to using the protocol counter
    \setcounter{algorithm}{\value{protocol}}% save the current number of algorithms
    \begin{algorithm}[#1]%
    }{\end{algorithm}
    \setcounter{protocol}{\value{algorithm}}% save the current number of protocols
    \setcounter{algorithm}{\value{algorithm saved}}% restore the algorithm counter
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \begin{algorithm}
        \caption{Algo Test}
        \label{algo:test}
        \begin{algorithmic}
            \State $x \gets y + 1$
        \end{algorithmic}
    \end{algorithm}

    \begin{protocol}
    \caption{Prot Test}
    \label{prot:test}
        \begin{algorithmic}
            \State $x \gets y + 1$
        \end{algorithmic}
    \end{protocol}

   \begin{algorithm}
        \caption{Algo Test}
        \label{algo:test}
        \begin{algorithmic}
            \State $x \gets y + 1$
        \end{algorithmic}
    \end{algorithm}

    \begin{protocol}
    \caption{Prot Test}
    \label{prot:test}
        \begin{algorithmic}
            \State $x \gets y + 1$
        \end{algorithmic}
    \end{protocol}

\end{document}
```

Here's the output:

[image]

Comment: I wouldn't use a space letter inside a counter name. Try `\thealgorithm saved` just for fun ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer You're right, of course, but in this instance this was a deliberate feature because you don't want anyone to touch the `algorithm saved` counter. This said, I also think it's kind of cute that this will be fine for a "normal" LaTeX user so long as they stick to using the "advertised" ways of working with counters like `\arabic{...}`, `\value{...}`, `\stepcounter{...}` etc for which this will work fine. Using the etoolbox, you also have `\csuse{thealgorithm saved}` -- or, `\csname thealgorithm saved\endcsname` if you prefer.

Comment: I am pretty aware about `\csuse` or \csname thealgorithm saved\endcsname`, but I don't recommend it anyway

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Of course you are Christian!

Comment: Well, +1 anyway ...

Comment: Thanks, guys. May I ask, for the future reference, where can I find such details? Any document or tutorial you'd recommend?