# Need help in latex algorithm and procedure format

Tags: algpseudocode

I would like to get the following output, but the code given below produces a different output.

[image]

Here is my code.

```
\documentclass[10pt,journal,compsoc]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
    \caption{This is Algo. 1}
    \textbf{Input: } The .  \\
    \textbf{Output: } .
    \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \State Here.....
    
    \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\floatname{algorithm}{Procedure}
\begin{algorithm}
    \caption{\textproc This is procedure 1 }
    
    \textbf{Input: } The.  \\
    \textbf{Output: } .
    
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
        
    \State Here....
        
    \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
    
\begin{algorithm}
    \caption{This is procedure 2}
    \textbf{Input: } The.  \\
    \textbf{Output: } .
    
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
        
    \State Here....
        
    \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}


\begin{algorithm}
    \caption{This is Algo. 2}
    \textbf{Input: } The. \\
    \textbf{Output: } . 
    
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
        
    \State Here .....
        
    \end{algorithmic}   
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Welcome to TEX.SX! Can you be specific about what is your problem?

Comment: Sorry I have posted a screenshot with this code but it didn't appear, actually I want this order of caption in the algorithm,
Algorithm 1: This is first Algo.
Procedure 1: This is first procedure.
Procedure 2: This is second procedure.
Algorithm 2: This is second Algorithm

But with above mention code output is like that,
Algorithm 1:
Procedure 2:
Procedure 3:
Procedure 4:

Comment: @Learner_104 I have edited the question. There was a typo in the raw code.

Comment: I think [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/387731/234654) would help (a different counter for the algorithm environment).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try out the following code, by defining a new counter `procedure` to do the job:

```
\documentclass[10pt,journal,compsoc]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}

\newcounter{procedure}
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{procedure}[1][htb]{%
  \let\c@algorithm\c@procedure
  \renewcommand{\ALG@name}{Procedure}% Update algorithm name
  \begin{algorithm}[#1]%
  }{\end{algorithm}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
    \caption{This is Algo. 1}
    \textbf{Input: } The .  \\
    \textbf{Output: } .
    \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \State Here.....
    
    \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\begin{procedure}
    \caption{\textproc This is procedure 1 }
    
    \textbf{Input: } The.  \\
    \textbf{Output: } .
    
    \begin{algorithmic}[1]
        
        \State Here....
        
    \end{algorithmic}
\end{procedure}
    
\begin{procedure}
    \caption{This is procedure 2}
    \textbf{Input: } The.  \\
    \textbf{Output: } .
    
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
        
    \State Here....
        
    \end{algorithmic}
\end{procedure}

\begin{algorithm}
    \caption{This is Algo. 2}
    \textbf{Input: } The. \\
    \textbf{Output: } . 
    
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
        
    \State Here .....
        
    \end{algorithmic}   
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

which is adapted from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/387731/234654).

[image: Result]

Comment: Thank you, that is very helpful

Comment: You are welcome. You may also use the tick icon to accept the answer, marking the problem being resolved :-)