# How to remove Algorithm 1 from header and how to declare a variable with its type

Tags: algorithm2e, pseudocode

I'm trying to write my first pseudocode algorithm with MikTEX and algorithm2e package but there are at least two things that I cannot understand. The image below shows what I want to achieve in term of final result.

First of all, I can't understand how to put the function name as the first line. I've tried with `\caption` and in other ways but I couldn't get rid of the text "**Algorithm 1**".
The second thing that I want to learn is: how can I declare a variable with its type? i.e *RBNode y*?

[image]

EDIT

Trying to make the question more clear:

1. How can I obtain an header (the first line of the image below) like this in the image below? I want that the text between the two black line contains only the function name and the list of parameters

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: First question is [captions - Changing label name for algorithm - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/104430/changing-label-name-for-algorithm) .

Answer (score 1):

To start with, you can rename the word "Algorithm" to anything you want using

`\SetAlgorithmName{Something}{List of Somethings}`

But that doesn't remove it. So instead you could give an empty string:

```latex
\usepackage[linesnumbered,ruled,vlined]{algorithm2e}
...
\SetAlgorithmName{}{List of Algorithms}
\begin{algorithm}
    RBNode $y \gets x$, right\\
    \caption{rotateLeft (RBNode $x$)}
\end{algorithm}
```

which produces this:

[image: eg1]

Though the number still remains in the header.

Another thing you can try is adding the `figure` option (and remove `ruled` if you want) to `\usepackage` which removes the entire line where "Algorithm 1" was. But then you'll have to write your function name as a line of code rather than in the caption (which is probably better anyways):

```latex
\usepackage[linesnumbered,vlined,figure]{algorithm2e}
\newcommand{\FuncCall}[2]{\texttt{\bfseries #1(#2)}}
\SetKwProg{Function}{function}{}{}
...
\begin{algorithm}
    \Function{rotateLeft(RBNode $x$)}{
        RBNode $y \gets x$, right\\
        more\\
        code\\
        here\\
    }
    \caption{Some caption here}
\end{algorithm}
```

which produces this:

[image]

For more formatting tips, this answer is a good place to start: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/534197/49045

And documentation for algorithm2e is at https://hal.inria.fr/file/index/docid/680365/filename/algorithm2e.sty